# How to properly initialize a list

Tags: flutter

So, i'm trying to initialize a list of int to 0 according to an item.lenght, but i keep getting the error **RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DisplayAttributes extends StatefulWidget {
  const DisplayAttributes({
    Key key,
    //@required this.attribute,
    this.data,
    this.variableProducts,
    Function onChanged,
  }) : super(key: key);

  //final Attributes attribute;
  final Product data;
  final List<ProductVariation> variableProducts;

  @override
  _DisplayAttributesState createState() => _DisplayAttributesState();
}

class _DisplayAttributesState extends State<DisplayAttributes> {
  int activeOption = 0; //to replace with
  List activeOptions = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    for (int i = 0; i >= this.widget.data.attributes.length; i++) {
      activeOptions[i] = 0;
    }
    print(this.widget.data.attributes.length); // returns 7
    print(activeOptions[0]); // returns RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: use `List.filled` constructor

Comment: Thanks, List.filled is working.. but why is it that what i wrote is not working??

Comment: beacuse  your list is empty so you cant even do `activeOptions[0] = 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `.filled` factory constructor

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
List.filled(this.widget.data.attributes.length, 0,growable: true);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you have stated
`List activeOptions = [];`, which means `activeOptions` is an empty list.

then you are trying to add value to it `activeOptions[i] = 0;`. This means at `i index` value is `0`. But in actual, `List activeOptions` is empty. So, this statement is wrong.

Right way is `activeOptions.add(0);`. This will add `0` to the List.

If you can share the complete code or the use of this function, maybe I can suggest you something else.